# KeyMatch not working

Tags: google-search-appliance

I have inherited a GSA installation (with no handover notes or instructions, just the manuals). I am trying to enable some features on the test appliance. I have setup some KeyMatch "ExactMatch" items, but when I search for the trigger terms the KeyMatch results do not appear.

I changed the show_keymatch to "1" in the XSLT and saved it (it was set to "0"). Here is that section of the XSLT as it appears now:

```
<!-- *** keymatch suggestions *** -->
<xsl:variable name="show_keymatch">1</xsl:variable>
<xsl:variable name="keymatch_text">KeyMatch</xsl:variable>
<xsl:variable name="keymatch_text_color">#2255aa</xsl:variable>
<xsl:variable name="keymatch_bg_color">#e8e8ff</xsl:variable>
```

Is there another area in the XSLT file, or in the admin interface, that I need to look at in order to enable keymatch?

I feel that I have followed all the instructions in the docs, but the lack of results tell me that I've missed something!

Any advice greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is always possible that the previous developer modified the XSLT and took out the code to display it or your search URL may not be using those keymatches.

Two things:

1) I recommend to create a new Front End and put your keymatches in there and test with that Front End.

2) In your search URL are proxystylesheet and client the same values?  If not, make sure they are the same and pointing to the Front End that contains the keymatch entries.

Comment: I made proxystylesheet and client the same and it worked as expected. Thanks for the tip, Terry!

Comment: You're welcome.  It's a good tip to know - you can use the same XSLT but have different Keymatch and other settings by modifying the parameters.  Be sure to read the Search Protocol Reference 7.4 documentation for a lot more details.